# How to stop Reactor flatMap if error occurs

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm loading data with Reactor chain:

```
 public Flux<Report> collectReport(List<MarkId> marks) {
        return Flux.fromIterable(marks)
                .flatMap(this::prepareRequest)
                .collectList()
                .flatMapIterable(e -> e)
                .delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(200))
                .concatMap(this::createReport)
                .retryWhen(retryConfig)
                .onErrorResume(throwable -> {
                    log.error(throwable.getMessage()); 
                    return Mono.empty();
                });
                .flatMap(response -> some actions here..//)
                .buffer(1000)
                .publishOn(Schedulers.newParallel("The rep saving", 4))
                .flatMap(googleAnalyticsReports -> {
                            //saving to database here
                        }
                );
    }
```

`concatMap(this::createReport)` may produce errors and retry will be executted. So, app will be stopped and will not send another requests before retries for one id is not exhausted.

To increase loading speed I decided to replace this `concatMap` with `flatMap`. But `flatMap` is not so predictable. Now if error occurs, app will continue sending requests from other threads ignoring fact that some of id already in `retry` case, and with this behaviour I'll continue get 429 error from server (API restrictions) before timeout is active.

So, **my question is:**  how can i stop loading data from flatMap and wait until all retries exhausted, if some specific error for specific id occured ? If i get 429 error, app should stop loading data for current id, then goes to retry case, where i can wait to pass timeout. While this id is not passed, app **should not sending another requests** for other ids from list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying is not possible with `flatMap`, for the simple reason that `flatMap` subscribes eagerly to the inner streams - that is, it won't wait for one stream to finish before it subscribes to the next one. Since createReport is asynchronous, as soon as the work is off-loaded to the `I/O` thread, `flatMap` will create a new stream from the next element and subscribe to it. Compare this to `concatMap` that waits for an inner stream to finish before subscribing to the next one.

What you want to do is a bit contradicting with itself - You want to increase the loading speed (so you want to parallelise the calls) but then you want an ordering b/w these requests. You want a request has to know about the status of any previous request. `flatMap` does not provide any ordering guarantees so you can't use this operator here.